# Split after first space in one cell and the rest in another

Tags: string, excel, split, excel-formula

I would like to know how to split a cell in Excel after the first space. Using Google I came across:

```
=LEFT(C2,FIND(" ",C2)-1)     (Formula 1 In D2)
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(" ",C2))     (Formula 2 In E2)
```

And that should do exactly what I want and need but sadly Excel (Office 2013) just tells me that the code is supposed to have an error.

For example my Table looks like this : (// means new cell)

```
Value//               Formula 1 //            Formula 2
BRAND ID1 ID2 ID3//   Formula 1//            Formula 2
```

Comment: Try replacing the commas with semi-colons. e.g. `=LEFT(C2; FIND(4" "; C2)-1)` and `=RIGHT(C2; LEN(C2)-FIND(" "; C2))`. Excel uses the computer's system regional setting's List Separator character between the parameters of a worksheet function. Some computers (notably European) use semi-colons instead of the EN-US standard use of commas.

Comment: Thanks alot! didnt know that, noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer for a German Excel:

```
=LINKS(C2;FINDEN(" ";C2)-1)
=RECHTS(C2;LÄNGE(C2)-FINDEN(" ";C2))
```

Unfortunately, Excel behaves differently in different languages (Obviously the worst thing the developer of a programming language can do).

In detail, the following things are known to depend on the language:

- Argument separator: English uses comma (`,`) where German and probably other languages use semicolon (`;`). The actual value is taken from the regional settings in windows (thx to Jeeped).
  Error message in Excel: *"The formula contains an error"*
- Function names: They are normally different for every supported language. You have to try their translation or lookup them. There are also translations tables in the www.
  Error behaviour in Excel: The cell value shows: *"#NAME!"*

Comment: Thanks alot! didnt know that, noted

Comment: Does anyone know how Excel behaves if I load a 'localized' excel file in an english Excel or vice versa? Does it convert the formulas? And some excel versions also use different keywords for VBA scripts. How about them?

Comment: if you want send me a file to kbo@hotmail.de and i can tell you (i´ve got german excel)